# Inserting a hotspot inside a rich text in using lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

What I need to do is to create a hotspot link and attached it inside a rich text. I already found a way to implement this by following this link:

http://ozinisle.blogspot.com/2010/11/lotusscript-code-to-append-hotspot-to.html

Now I want the created hotspot to be inside or in the middle of an existing rich text field. If you checked the link it creates a document with a body rich text for the hotspot, I can't identify inserting it inside tried using nav and range but it just gets the plain text, I also want to get the hotspot link. Thanks.

Here is a sample codes (where we append the rich text, but I want to insert it inside - I found a way but it's confusing also using DXL) is there a easy way to solve this:

```
If rtnav.FindFirstString("<Reply: From>", RT_FIND_CASEINSENSITIVE) Then

    ' Get the <Reply:From> string
    Call rtrange.SetBegin(rtnav)
    Call rtrange.SetEnd(rtnav)

    ' Remove the <Reply:From> string
    Call rtrange.Remove()

    ' Go to the next text range after the <Reply:From> string
    Call rtrange.SetBegin(rtnav)
    Call rtrange.SetEnd(rtnav)

    ' Insert the hotspot in the right place
    Call rtitem.BeginInsert(rtrange, False)

    ' ** I WANT TO INSERT HERE THE HOTSPOT, BUT I CAN'T FIGURE IT OUT **

    Call rtitem.EndInsert

    Call rtitem.AppendRTItem(dxlbody)

End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I was able to accomplish my goal by basically applying or using DXL. I manipulated the two rich text DXL thus I was able to insert the hotspot link inside the rich text. Though it requires a lot of codes and it's bit confusing it can be indeed accomplished by that.

Thanks for everyone's help specially to Richard and Ken.

I used this source:

http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/How-to-insert-RichText-into-RichText-using-LotusScript

Answer (score 1):

I looked at a very similar problem about five years ago, and I was unable to find a solution. I settled for putting the hotstpot at the beginning instead of in the middle -- i.e., by copying a NotesRichTextItem containing a "prototype" hotspot from an existing configuration document, and inserting that into a new NotesRichText item, then copying the NotesRichTextItem containing the rich text that I'm pre-pending it to.

Note: this could undoubtedly be done using the Midas Rich Text API, but that is a commercial product from Genii Software and I was not in a position where I could use that.

Comment: Hi Richard, I understand what you meant so basically there is no way to apply that? Actually I did something by getting all the element inside the rich text and finding where it should be entered. I was able to do it but the thing is the (text style) was gone and even the proper space, so it does not look right. 

I was hoping that there is some alternative, I really need to apply it. Though I tried doing any alternatives I know but I still can't apply it. I feel like I am desperate to solve this.

Comment: I did not investigate using DXL. I think that to apply the technique I used, you would still have to find a way to "break" the existing NotesRichTextItem into two NotesRichTextItems -- with the break occurring at the right place. In my case, I was dealing with arbitary rich text fields that could contain anything at all, so there really was no possibility of even looking for the right place, because I didn't know what would be there.

Comment: yes I agree, that would be a problem once the rich text contains every kind of element. I will try using DXL again if it can be applied, if ever you found a solution please do share it richard. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is very old and may not work in later versions, but I remember many years ago using an undocumented method to create doclinks.

*Defined In*

**NotesRichTextItem**

*Syntax*

```
Call notesRichTextItem.AddLinkByIds( dbReplicaID$, serverHint$, viewUNID$, documentUNID$, comment$ [, HotSpotText$ ])
```

Parameters

**serverHint$**

String. ServerName in Canonical or Common format.

**viewUNID$**

String. UniversalID of the notesview you want to use for opening the document. Use an empty string ("") to create database link if no documentUNID is specified, or to use the default view for opening docLinks.

**documentUNID$**

String. UniversalID of the document you want to link to. Use an empty string ("") to create a view Link or database Link.

**comment$**

String. The text that appears when a user presses and holds the mouse pointer over the link.

**HotSpotText$**

Optional. String. If supplied, the HotSpotText will appear in the RichTextItem as boxed text which can be clicked on with the mouse to follow the link. In this case, no other token appears in the text.

Taken from:
http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Creating-DocLinks-using-undocumented-lotusscript-method

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for sharing this information. That functions is probably an old one since I checked the help and it is not included anymore but it would help me in the future if ever (I am a New LN Dev). The thing is I am not trying to create a doc link since I can insert it anywhere. What I need to attach in the middle of the rich text is a hotspot button where it contains formula. If you ever know a way please do share it. Thanks a lot Ken!

Comment: Ahh, I see.  First thought - you won't find this in help.  This is an undocumented feature :)  I'll update my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Scratch that - My other idea is similar to Richard's.  In the past I've created a rich-text item on a hidden profile document and then I would access that item and append it to my current document wherever needed.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part, though the thing is I want it to be added inside the rich text around the middle. Only append can be done as of now, for two rich text items. I am manipulating it with DXL, though it's really confusing.

Comment: Ken! This 8 years old answer of yours just saved my day! It still exists in 12.0.1, so even undocumented features are maintained... wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

```
'This works in lotusscript:
rs4.PassThruHTML= True
Call rtitem.AppendStyle(rs4)
rtitem.appendText(|<a href="http://www.teamwork.com.tr">Open</a>|)
rs4.PassThruHTML= False
Call rtitem.AppendStyle(rs4)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.