# Lotus Designer link hotspot to database resource

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I want to create a hotspot link to a database resource.  Anyone has idea on how to do?

Comment: Which database resource you want to access? Image? File?

Comment: What is the purpos of this? I think the best answer can be given if you tel, us, what you really want to achieve, not how you think you could achieve it...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no supported Lotusscript methods to help you with this (maybe in newer versions there are?), but here are some ideas to help you:

[Inserting a hotspot inside a rich text in using lotusscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803429/inserting-a-hotspot-inside-a-rich-text-in-using-lotusscript)

[A post in the Notes 7 forum had a suggestion](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/54b55fa290addbca8525705e005f72dc?OpenDocument)

Comment: I want to insert this into a page as just a hotspot or button.  Not in a rich text field.  There has to be a way.

Comment: Please update your question with the answers to this comment - The more detail you can provide, the better.  I assumed you were trying to do this via Lotusscript or formulas, based on the tags you provided, is that correct? Are you trying to edit a form/page design element programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

On your page design element, type your link text, then select it.

From the top-line menu, select Create, then Hotspot, choosing either Link Hotspot or Action Hotspot.

Link Hotspot lets you select some Named Elements, but not resources, so better to write the URL link for the file resource or whatever it is.

Action Hotspot will let you use LotusScript. If you're just after a resource, you probably want to use the URLOpen method of the NotesUIWorkspace.

Of course, if it's just a file you want them to download, better just to use Create, Attachment from the top line menu and attach the file to the page design element.